# Trying to replace a toilet's water supply line

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I'm investigating replacing my toilet's water supply line/the possibility of installing a bidet.

This is what my current supply line looks like
[image]

From what I can tell, there's no easy way to replace this type of hose without replacing the water shut off line, but I'm a bit scared to attempt that as I have no idea how difficult it is, nor do I particularly want to do it if I don't need to.

Is there a way to replace this style supply line easily, or am I going to need to replace the line + the shutoff valve?

Comment: This looks like a common compression fitting line that should come right off of the valve.  Have you tried to remove it and had difficulty?

Comment: I agree a replacement can be found at any home store or plumbing specialty. Show them the photo, very common.+

Comment: @JPhi1618 Not yet, I tried removing the supply line in a previous apartment I lived in and had to get the complexes maintenance crew involved to get it fixed, this one looked similar so I wanted to get as much information as possible before messing with it.

Comment: why are you replacing the water line?

Comment: @jsotola I'd like to replace it with one in better shape + most likely will install a Bidet and I do not believe the current supply line will be flexible enough to install a T-valve.

Comment: It looks almost new.

Comment: the metal hexgonal nut at the bottom of the grey pipe unscrews from te valve the white hexagonal cap at the top of the grey pipe also unscrews, undo do that end first

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned, the gray hose is connected with a compression fitting at the bottom, and maybe a pre-crimped fitting at the top. In any case, they thread right off.

I'd go buy a stainless mesh-wrapped hose in the next length up from what you need and with the correct end fittings (standard for a toilet). These will have integrated seals, so just snug them up slightly.

Put a slight corkscrew twist in it to take up the slack. It'll look great.

Optionally replace the valve with a nice clean new one and shorten the supply pipe to get it closer to the wall. This will require a compression fitting, but they're not difficult if you start with a clean pipe. Be sure to use two wrenches, one on the valve body and one on the connection nut, so as not to strain the pipe.